# Same contract can have different contract creation code?

Tags: solidity, bsc, hardhat

Deploying a factory contract in Hardhat console and BSC testnet gives me different `INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH`  using the line of code below. `Pair` is a contract imported externally and should be the same in two environment. The only explanation is the creation code is different if the other components, like `keccak256`, `abi.encodePacked` and `type(C)` have the same effects.

```
 bytes32 public constant INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(Pair).creationCode));
```

In the Hardhat console, the hashed value is:
`0x9348867049a36c208e79be9fad349bc0c1796ee0f5d79c255d2936ac946a8ce1`

In the BSC testnet, the hashed value is:
`0x84e322481e3d7674187c70a7f8b92cce721243b37f5385015a3be236f152c6c5`

Comment: Never mind. It turns out to be an issue caused by optimizer settings.